# Improve android canvas rendering

Tags: java, android, canvas, surfaceview

I am developing a 2d platformer shooter game for android devices. I notice that while playing the game there is sometimes a frame drop (in most of the cases it drops from 60 fps to 40-45) which causes the game to be a little laggy. I analyzed the performance using the Profiler tool in Android studio. I found that sometimes locking the canvas or drawing a bitmap takes a huge amount of time (50ms up to 500ms).

Most of the time the game can run at 60 fps this frame drop happens once in 3-4 seconds. I searched for ways to improve rendering in the code, I created all my paints and bitmaps before the game starts, and removed any Object initialization inside my drawing functions and some other improvements that i found here: http://www.independent-software.com/android-speeding-up-canvas-drawbitmap.html.

Is there any way to improve that? Should i replace canvas with openGL? Will it solve my problem?

Comment: Is there any heap allocation in your `onDraw` method or just stack allocation?  I ask because the "lag" could be a result of garbage collection - maybe check the memory allocation or GC rate and see if this coincides with frame drops.  Does your `onDraw` method have a consistent Big O time/space?

Comment: The provided link is broken.